# C header causes errors when included in some files but not others

Tags: c, header

The title pretty much says it all. The precise error message that seems to be the root of it is:

> util.h:4: error: expected declaration
>   specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’

The header in question is:

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H

void print_array(void*, int, size_t, void (*)(void*));
extern void print_int(void*);
extern void print_float(void*);

#endif /* UTIL_H */
```

If I compile the following file with `gcc -Wall -c util.c` the compiler silently creates an object file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "util.h"

void print_array(void* a, int length, size_t size, void (*print)(void*)) {
  unsigned int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    print(a + i*(unsigned int)size);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void print_int(void* i) {
  int* a = (int*) i;
  printf(" %i ", *a); 
}

void print_float(void* f) {
  float* a = (float*) f;
  printf(" %f ", *a);
}
```

If I include it with any other file, I get the aforementioned error and a bunch of other ones. The one I've provided comes first. Everything I've googled about it says that it's the result of a syntax error on a previous line but it was happening when it was the *first line* in the file. I can see that if I get this error knocked out, then all the other ones will go away as they have to do with `print_array` being called with the wrong number or type of arguments (which it isn't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size_t` isn't defined until you include `stddef.h`. Your header should probably include that first to guarantee it's defined. (As it stands, you're just getting "lucky" and having other includes that will eventually define it included first, so it doesn't cause a problem.)

Comment: oi this is embarrasing. I have to wait ten minutes to accept your answer. If anybody as a rep to spare, I deserve a downvote or two for this.

Comment: @aaronasterling, don't sweat it.  Sometimes the best part about programming is when you get to feel smart and dumb at the same time. ;-)

Comment: What about `<sys/types.h>` for `size_t`?

Comment: @jørgensen: If you have that header and want to use it you can, I prefer to use standard headers when possible.

Comment: `<sys/types.h>` should largely be considered deprecated, and especially should not be used for getting at standard C types (since it's specific to POSIX and legacy unices, not standard C). Just about the only legitimate use I can think of for `<sys/types.h>` is for situations where you want to prototype POSIX standard library functions yourself (perhaps to get access to a function without pulling in other declarations or macros that would conflict with your code) but need a particular type defined for their arguments/return values.